# SQL Query Help on 3 Tables with a Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server

I had an issue joining multiple tables to retrieve the data I needed.  In order to accomplish the proper results I had to first create a view (shown below) called: vwinvgrossrev :

```
SELECT     dbo.inv_item.inv_num, dbo.inv_item.co_line, 
dbo.inv_hdr.co_num, dbo.inv_hdr.inv_date, dbo.inv_item.qty_invoiced, 
dbo.inv_item.price
FROM         dbo.inv_item INNER JOIN
dbo.inv_hdr ON dbo.inv_item.inv_num = dbo.inv_hdr.inv_num
```

and then I had to join the view on my final table in order to create a proper summation of the values that I wanted

```
select sum(vwinvgrossrev.qty_invoiced*vwinvgrossrev.price) 
from     vwinvgrossrev,coitem
WHERE vwinvgrossrev.co_num=coitem.co_num 
AND coitem.Uf_Erne='Y'
AND vwinvgrossrev.co_line=coitem.co_line
AND DATEPART(mm,vwinvgrossrev.inv_date) = DATEPART(mm,Getdate()) 
AND YEAR(vwinvgrossrev.inv_date) = YEAR(Getdate())
```

My question is this.  Is there anyway to do this in a single query.  The problem is all 3 tables have a many to many relationship with one another and always returns the wrong value when joining all 3 tables.

Comment: Not sure why you needed to create a view for just this query. You really should start using the "newer" join syntax instead of the comma delimited list of tables. It has been the preferred join syntax for more than 2 decades now. You also have some serious performance potentials in here because of the nonSARGable predicates in your where clause. In order to help we need more information that a couple table names and some columns. We need to know what the structures look like. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: As to the View, why not? It is precompiled and so will execute faster than the raw sql. It will also probably be of use elsewhere in the application. If you can do it in a view then do it in a view.

Comment: Sean: As it is written above, it works and gives me the results that I am looking for, I was just posting it here to see if anyone out there knows how to fine tune it a bit.  If you know how to do this with a "newer" join, I'd love to hear it (or read it, in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current query (using the view) gives you what you are looking for then I believe that this query will give you the same thing in a single query:

```
SELECT sum(inv_item.qty_invoiced*inv_item.price) 
FROM     inv_item
JOIN inv_hdr ON dbo.inv_item.inv_num = dbo.inv_hdr.inv_num
JOIN coitem ON (inv_hdr.co_num=coitem.co_num 
    AND inv_item.co_line=coitem.co_line)
WHERE coitem.Uf_Erne='Y'
AND vwinvgrossrev.co_line=coitem.co_line
AND DATEPART(mm,inv_hdr.inv_date) = DATEPART(mm,Getdate()) 
AND YEAR(inv_hdr.inv_date) = YEAR(Getdate())
```

However, I'll be surprised if that is what you are looking for.

I am assuming that you don't actually have a many-to-many between all 3. I am assuming that inv_hdr has a unique inv_num and inv_item has many of those.  Similarly I am assuming that co_num is unique within inv_hdr but has multiple occurrences within coitem.  These are not many-to-many but rather 1-to-many relationships. Since `SELECT` multiplies rows I think you are going to be summing way more than you want.

Why do you want to include `coitem` at all if you are just interested in `inv_item.qty_invoiced` and `inv_item.price`? Is it just to limit on the Uf_Erne column? Is `coitem` always going to have either 1 or 0 records for that `co_num` and `co_line` with `Uf_Erne='Y'`?

In sum, I've reproduced your query in a single query without a view, but I think you may need to think through whether this is really what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I didn't design the database, but after doing a quick search there is a many to many on the co_num field between all 3 tables ... and a one to many on the inv_num field between the inv_hdr table and the inv_item table.

Comment: I just tested what you wrote and it worked perfectly!

Comment: So you may have more than 1 row in coitem which has the co_num and co_line from inv_hdr? (Please check - note I'm asking about BOTH columns.)  But if you have this then you don't want to add up your extended price 2 or 3 or 4 times, depending on how many rows are in coitem with Uf_Erne='Y' - have I correctly understood? If so, you could use an EXISTS sub-query, probably. I'll show you how, but please confirm my understanding first.

Comment: It was  
    JOIN inv_hdr ON dbo.inv_item.inv_num = dbo.inv_hdr.inv_num
    JOIN coitem ON (inv_hdr.co_num=coitem.co_num
    AND inv_item.co_line=coitem.co_line)  
that I kept getting stuck on ... I have to work on my joins better ... Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

You need to refine your database schema to normalise out the many-to-many relationships. That is a given and is standard practice regardless of your current problem. The fact that it will simplify your current problem is the reason why. There are many tutorials/blog/etc out there to show you how to do this with join tables so I am not going into it here.

Comment: I agree with your first sentiment ... however I don't have the authority or permission set to do that, so I have to work with what I have.